# Is there somewhere I can submit SQL code and have the website display a graphic?

Tags: sql, oracle, web-applications, diagram

I'm trying to create a graphs of my database. Is there somewhere online that offers this service for free?

I think it would be a great tool. :)

EDIT:

Turning this

```
CREATE TABLE pertipoempleado
  (
     id_tipoempleado INT primary key,
     descripcion     VARCHAR2(200)
  );

CREATE TABLE perarea
  (
     id_area      INT primary key,
     nombre       VARCHAR2(200),
     id_areapadre INT references perarea(id_area)
  );

CREATE TABLE pertipoobservacion
  (
     id_tipoobservacion INT primary key,
     descripcion        VARCHAR2(200)
  );

CREATE TABLE perestadocivil
  (
     id_estadocivil INT primary key,
     descripcion    VARCHAR2(40)
  );

CREATE TABLE pertipocontrato
  (
     id_tipocontrato INT primary key,
     descripcion     VARCHAR2(500)
  );

CREATE TABLE persexo
  (
     id_sexo     INT primary key,
     descripcion VARCHAR2(40)
  );

CREATE TABLE percargo
  (
     id_cargo    INT primary key,
     descripcion VARCHAR2(200)
  );

CREATE TABLE perturno
  (
     id_turno    INT primary key,
     descripcion VARCHAR2(200)
  );

CREATE TABLE perafp
  (
     id_afp      INT primary key,
     descripcion VARCHAR2(200),
     descuento   FLOAT
  );

CREATE TABLE pertiposangre
  (
     id_tiposangre INT primary key,
     descripcion   VARCHAR2(20)
  );

CREATE TABLE pertiposeguro
  (
     id_tiposeguro INT primary key,
     descripcion   VARCHAR2(300)
  );

CREATE TABLE performpago
  (
     id_formapago INT primary key,
     descripcion  VARCHAR2(300)
  );

CREATE TABLE perempleado
  (
     id_empleado                INT primary key,
     id_tipoempleado            INT references pertipoempleado(id_tipoempleado),
     id_area                    INT references perarea(id_area),
     id_cargo                   INT references percargo(id_cargo),
     id_empleadopadre           INT references peremplado(id_empleado),
     id_estadocivil             INT references perestadocivil(id_estadocivil),
     id_sexo                    INT references persexo(id_sexo),
     id_tipocontrato            INT references pertipocontrato(id_tipocontrato),
     id_formapago               INT references performapago(id_formapago),
     numerodecuenta             INT,
     bancopago                  VARCHAR2(2000),
     id_tiposangre              INT references pertiposangre(id_tiposangre),
     notificaraccidentenombre   VARCHAR2(500),
     notificaraccidentetelefono VARCHAR2(100),
     fechaingreso               DATE,
     fechabaja                  DATE,
     gradoinstruccion           VARCHAR2(200),
     id_tiposeguro              INT references pertiposeguro(id_tiposeguro),
     nombre                     VARCHAR2(200),
     apellido                   VARCHAR2(200),
     foto                       VARCHAR2(2000),
     id_turno                   INT references perturno(id_turno),
     id_afp                     INT references perafp(id_afp),
     fechadenacimiento          VARCHAR2(200),
     lugardenacimiento          VARCHAR2(500),
     carnet                     INT,
     direccion                  VARCHAR2(200),
     telefono                   VARCHAR2(30),
     celular                    VARCHAR2(30)
  );

CREATE TABLE perhistoriallaboral
  (
     id_historiallaboral INT primary key,
     id_empleado         INT references perempleado(id_empleado),
     cargo               VARCHAR2(400),
     detalle             VARCHAR2(400)
  );

CREATE TABLE percurriculum
  (
     id_curriculum     INT primary key,
     id_empleado       INT references perempleado(id_empleado),
     location          VARCHAR2(2000),
     tituloprofesional VARCHAR2(500),
     habilidades       VARCHAR2(400)
  );

CREATE TABLE perobservaciones
  (
     id_observaciones INT primary key,
     id_empleado      INT references perempleado(id_empleado),
     detalle          VARCHAR2(2000)
  );
```

into a beautiful graphic representation of the database.

Comment: Graph of what? What kind of code? A `SELECT`? A database generation script?

Comment: I think he's talking about generating an ERD from a DDL script.

Comment: https://drawerd.com can import ddl to erd, you can try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know of an online ERD, but there are a couple of open source tools to do this. See the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137854/free-oss-data-model-diagram-generator-from-ddl)

Could be a nice little project to upload a DDL script, and generate the diagram and present it as a JPG/GIF/PDF (or email it back).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's SQLDeveloper has a tool called data modeler. It creates a diagram from the tables in your schema.